# Cross project dependencies and circular dependencies

Tags: jdeveloper, jdeveloper-11g

The *Java EE Web Application* wizard creates an application structure with two projects:

- Model
- ViewController

The way they're linked is that at *ViewController/ Project properties/ Dependencies* you can find Model as dependency for ViewController. So far so good: I can invoke EJB model entities from my view services.

However, it doesn't seem possible to use a class defined at ViewController from Model. If you set ViewController as dependency for Model you get a nasty warning about circular dependencies.

> Warning: Project Model.jpr has a circular dependency with ViewController.jpr. Check your project dependencies.

As far as I know there's nothing in Java itself that prevents programs from doing so. How can you cross project boundaries in both directions when using JDeveloper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about different dependencies. The warning is a result of a build dependency, not a Java warning. From Java's point of view, you would only need to add the jar created by the ViewController to the Model to get what you want. The problem is how to tell the build system the order to create the jars. The view jar might need changes that are currently built in the Model and the other way around. So the built might fail too.

If you need a class in both Model and View, you can either put it directly into the Model or introduce a third project and the dependency of the Modeland View to the third project.

Comment: JDeveloper doesn't even allow to compile *.java files that import a package from a project that isn't configured as dependency. Is it then because it can't find the *.class files so it assume something's broken, bug Java compiler wouldn't really complain as long as they're present in the class path?

Comment: Well, a project is a boundary. If there is no dependency, direct to the other project or indirect if you add the jar produced by the other project, JDev doesn't know about the class. Only classes on the source path are compiled. Classes are read from a jar or from the other project's classes path of there is a dependency defined.